# Lodash merge properties of object that are not in object already

Tags: javascript, lodash

I have an object:

```
var props = {//values here};

this.options: {
    cssSelectorAncestor: props.cssSelectorAncestor,
    media: {
        autoPlay: props.autoPlay,
        muted: props.muted
    }   
}

this.options = _.merge(
{
    defaultPlaybackRate: 1.0,
    minPlaybackRate: 0.5
}, props);
```

How do I merge all of the properties in props **apart** from the ones that have already been assigned to options.

Consider props immutable.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I'm just guessing here, because I'm having trouble following your sample code, but I think you want [defaults()](https://lodash.com/docs#defaults):

```
const result = _.defaults({ foo: true }, { foo: false, bar: true });
// ➜ { foo: true, bar: true }
```

This will only merge in properties that don't already exist.

Answer (score 0):

Merge all three objects into an empty object. Make sure you do it in the right order. The keys with highest priority go on the right.